Conditions for $ \int_{\Gamma}f = \lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \int_{\Gamma \epsilon} f $
Theorem 7.7 in Bak-Neumann's Complex Analysis book states:

Suppose f is continuous in an open set D and analytic there except possibly at the points of a line segment L. Then f is analytic throughout D.

The proof proceeds looking at a function f defined in some open set D which we assume to overlap the real line and have all points of non-analyticity laying on the real line.
A bit further into the proof, an argument then is stated as follows:

Then:
$$ \int_{\Gamma}f = \lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \int_{\Gamma \epsilon} f $$
since
$$ \int_{a}^{b}f(x+i\epsilon)dx \to \int_{a}^{b} f(x)dx $$
by the coninuity of f.

My question is specifically about this. I'm used to interchange of limits (e.g. between integration and sequence of functions such as $f_n = f(z + \frac{1}{n})$) done freely when we have uniform convergence of some sort (which in this case would imply uniform continuity of $f$ I believe), but we are only told f is continuous.
Is this possible because we are specifically talking about a "shift" / linear operation, hence we can justify it directly? e.g. I can think of some argument as follows:
f is analytic in the open set $D$ above and below real line, hence if we limit ourselves to (simply connected) subsets of $D$ that do not intersect the real line, f has an antiderivative there, $F$.
We then have:
$$ \int_{a}^{b}f(x+i\epsilon)dx = \int_{a+i\epsilon}^{b+i\epsilon}f(x)dx = (F(b + i\epsilon) - F(a)) - (F(a+i\epsilon) - F(a))$$
where the above are simple straight line integrals, and by continuity of F we can say then that $\lim_{\epsilon \to 0}(F(b + i\epsilon) - F(a)) - (F(a+i\epsilon) - F(a)) = F(b) - F(a)$
Is that a valid way to arrive at the argument? Is there a standard way to make such a claim otherwise?

continuity of $f$ on a compact set $K$ implies uniform continuity on $K$, so $f(\cdot + i\epsilon)$ converges uniformly to $f$ on $[a, b]$.

Kakashi thank you - in this case I find it complicated a bit by the fact we are operating in $\mathbb{C}$ and specifically using an imaginary unit as part of the argument ($i \epsilon$) so we are not strictly within [a, b] no?

You can take $K = [a,b] \cup ([a, b] + i/10000000000)$.
